# How to run a browser in a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

What's the code to open a Chrome extension pop-down that shows basically a new tab and how to input a new url.

So far I've only gotten a google.com window to show using 'http://www.google.com/custom?q=&btnG=Search' in this iframe..

```
  <iframe id="if1" ng-if="!iframeURL" width="100%" height="100%" style="visibility:visible" src="http://www.google.com/custom?q=&btnG=Search"></iframe>
```

But I want to also input any url. essentially, i'm looking for an omnibox and browser window inside of the chrome extension popup.

A chrome app has webviews, same functionality in an extension?https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview

**EDIT:**
*Hacky solution*
using angularJS to display secure content. This works for all sites that don't disallow x-browser requests. Still looking for a non-iframe, more webview solution...

HTML

```
  <iframe width="100%" height="500" ng-src="{{currentProjectUrl | trustAsResourceUrl}}"> </iframe>
```

JS

```
'use strict';
angular.module('irth', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope){

    $scope.currentProjectUrl = 'http://www.duckduckgo.com/';

})
.filter('trustAsResourceUrl', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(val);
    };
}]);
```

Comment: do you want to open a new url in new tab or inside the popup of extension?

Comment: inside of the popup. thanks

Comment: then add this iframe code in your `popup.html` what's problem in this

Comment: it only works with this url.. i want to put any arbitrary url and display as if it was a tab or window of it's own